# Exception In Inserting Image Into SQL Table Using BLOB Object

Tags: java, swing, io, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am getting the exception in the following code

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://Irfan:1433/Pictures", "sa", "ent@");      

java.sql.Blob bl=GetBolbDataFromDB();
InputStream fs = bl.getBinaryStream();
len = bl.length() ;

query = ("insert into NewPics2 VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, model);
pstmt.setString(2, catid);
pstmt.setString(3, ornid);
**pstmt.setBinaryStream(4, fs);**
```

The full Stack Trace is as follows

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Orders.CheckPrice.GetPicInfo(CheckPrice.java:1157)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Orders.CheckPrice.txtModelNoKeyPressed(CheckPrice.java:2300)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Orders.CheckPrice.access$1500(CheckPrice.java:37)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Orders.CheckPrice$18.keyPressed(CheckPrice.java:702)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1908)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put your jdbc driver does not implement the newest version of jdbc: it has no method setBinaryStream(). That means you cannot use it. You might try setBlob() with the fully read image.

Comment: the other answers might be alternatives. You can try them as well (for different versions of jdbc support different overloads of that method)

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it appears the method you have called is abstract.  According to the documentation,  [JtdsPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream()](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/doc/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsPreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream,%20int%29) takes three arguments: the index, the stream, and the length.

Try adding an `int` as the length parameter in: `pstmt.setBinaryStream(4, fs);`

Answer (score 0):

Try converting

```
java.sql.Blob bl=GetBlobDataFromDB();
String fs = bl.getBytes();
```